# Parity doesn't work

Tags: parity

I just downloaded parity following the instructions [here](https://www.cryptocompare.com/wallets/guides/how-to-use-the-parity-ethereum-wallet/).

after step 7 I get:

[image]

is this a bug, or is it just taking a really long time?

Comment: Did it finish syncing? Does Chrome or Firefox show the same?

Comment: Which version is that, do you know?

Comment: @Cristian -good call.  tried it now with firefox, and it -does- seem to work!  and yes, I think this is the latest version.  or close to.  firefox also originally displayed the loading screen, but only very briefly.